# Delete files from 00012 to 00441 using Terminal

Tags: bash, macos, range, leading-zero, brace-expansion

This is my Bash version:
**3.2.57(1)-release**

I found that this MIGHT possible using terminal `rm code`, but it doesn't work for me

Here is a picture of the first files:
[Picture of a bunch of Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9anNV.png)

Typing `rm _{00012..00441}` I get this error:
[Terminal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2Ndk.png)

Seems like the code us unable to use the leading zeros since is trying to find the files like 12,13,14,15, instead of 00012,00013,00014,00015

To make things more difficult, the last file in the range has a different amount of leading zeros, so using `rm _000{` wont work

In trying to use AppleScript to run this as

```
do shell script ("rm  _{" & STARTrange & ".." & ENDrange & "}.psd")
```

Comment: Add your bash version to your question.

Comment: Leading zeros in brace expansions was added in version 4.0.

Comment: @CyrusThat was a good clue about this, I used homebrew to install the latest version of Bash (4.4.19), its working now with plain m _{00012..00441}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Cyrus I made this work. The answer in OSX is to install the latest version of Bash using homebrew.

Using this guide I was able to change the default Bash from terminal to the one Homebre installs: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193411/update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this command.

```
find ./ -name "_0*.psd" -type f -delete;
```

Answer (score 0):

For versions of `bash` older than *v4.0* either of these should work:

1. `rm _000{12..99} _00{100..441}`
2. `rm $(printf '_%.5i ' {12..441})`